# if $|\int_a^b f\cdot g|=(\int_a^bf^2)^{1/2}\cdot (\int_a^bg^2)^{1/2}$ are f and g linearly dependent?

Tags: calculus

This one is from Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

if $|\int_a^b f\cdot g|=(\int_a^bf^2)^{1/2}\cdot (\int_a^bg^2)^{1/2}$

if f and g are continuous must $f=\lambda g$??

I don't know where to start with this one.

Comment: In both cases the answer is NO: take $g(x)=0$ for all $x$. Then equality holds for any $f$ because both sides are $0$.

Comment: Where to start.  Check the proof of the inequality.  See where you have $\le$ in it.  What would it mean if this is actually $=$ ?  Do this for the whole proof, you will end up with some facts about the case of $=$ . Then try to deduce your answer $f=\lambda g$ from this list of facts.  Actually, you may not be able to do that in case $g=0$ but $f \ne 0$.  But you can deduce: either $f=\lambda g$ or $g = \lambda f$ for some $\lambda$.

Comment: Fair enough, but what if f and g can't be 0? I understand that if f and g are not continuous than the statement isn't true because we can change them at discrete points and the integral doesn't change. But what about the continuous case? GEdgar I don't understand what you mean. I proved that the inequality holds, using the hint to look at $\int (f-\lambda g)$. Now they are asking for the other way around.

Comment: You may look into Hölder inequality and the condition for equality to hold.